# Adding an 'onclick' event to a button created by javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a card that is created every time a button is pressed, one of the parts of the card is the remove icon. I want to remove the card when the remove button is clicked. i am using this code:

```
let icon = document.createElement('span');
    icon.className = "span_x";
    document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0].appendChild(icon);
    document.getElementsByClassName('span_x')[0].innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>';
    icon.addEventListener('click', removeTask());
```

i tried the last line of code in a few ways, like:

```
icon.onclick = function()
icon.setAttribute("onclick","removeTask()");
```

but whatever i'm trying, it always runs the function when creating the card (task), even though i didn't clicked on the icon.
i hope i'm being clear enough. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
xBtn.addEventListener('click', removeTask);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the brackets. You're invoking the function right away, when you just need to pass a reference to it

```
icon.setAttribute("onclick", removeTask)
```

```js
const removeTask = () => {
  console.log('clicked')
}

let icon = document.createElement('span');
icon.className = "span_x";
document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0].appendChild(icon);
document.getElementsByClassName('span_x')[0].innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>';
icon.addEventListener('click', removeTask);
```

```css
.close {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.span_x:after {
  content: 'Click'
}
```

```html
<div class="close"></div>
```